# Power analysis for Spearman correlation in R

Tags: r, statistical-power, spearman-rho

I am wondering if the function `pwr.r.test()` in R can be used for all correlation coefficients. Does it matter if I add Spearman, Kendall or Pearson coefficient?

Comment: Thank you for asking a new question.  Note that questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: As a hint, consider that the stated function is just implementing standard formulas. Any power analysis software would be using the same formulas 'under the hood'.